# Remover seta para baixo de um ComboBox

Tags: delphi, combobox

Quero usar um `TComboBox` com a propriedade `style = csDropDown` como se fosse um `TEdit`.
Mas porque usar um `TComboBox` então? Porque quero apenas uma funcionalidade dele, o `AutoComplete`.
Porém quero remover a seta para baixo que fica no canto direito do componente. Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Tente setar o `style` como `csSimple`.

Comment: @Phiter hehe fiquei até com vergonha agora, vlw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O comboBox é Bem interessante, eu testei aqui como você quer é funcionou...
com `style = csSimple`.
Você mais ele só completa com os nome previamente inseridos na propriedade `Items`.

Comment: Realmente, mas esse não é o problema... alimento ele dentro de um *laço*.. Obrigado.